# cellForRowAtIndexPath how to call it only once and not after a scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview

every time I scroll up or down, and cell which has been drawn already gets redrawn because "cellForRowAtIndexPath" is called again when that cell comes in view.

Is there a way to not call "cellForRowAtIndexPath" for a cell that has already been called for.

That is once cellForRowAtIndexPath is called for a indexpath it should not call it again when the user scrolls.

I can set flags in a flag array and do it manually but is there a more direct way?

I have most definitely a design that is causing performance issues. I can't explain the design nor change it therefore I am asking.

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will get called when you scroll. You can't get away from that. You will have to move your draw code somewhere else if you are experiencing performance problems.

Comment: Why is it a problem for you that the table view sends you `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` again?  What happens that you don't like?

Comment: there is a horizontal scrollview in each row. cant explain why but thats how my design is. the scrollview in some scenarios is several pages wide and takes time to draw each time. thus the performance issue, thus the question

Answer (score 2):

If you do not let the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method calling again, it may create performance issue, 
But you can do that by assigning different cell identifier for each row as follows.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d", indexPath.row, indexPath.section]];
```

Comment: How bad of a performance issue do you think this could be? If i only have like 15-20 cells but NEED a way to uniquely reference each cell, should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

//TRY TO REMOVE ALL CONTENT BEFORE CREATING NEW.

//USE IN "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method

```
 for(UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews){
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is a very bad approach. you should use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier to get already created cells, not remove and re-create them.